# How to anchor a WPF Popup to a Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, wpf-positioning

I have decided to use templated PopUps to display validation errors for my controls, rather than ToolTips (seem to offer greater flexibility in terms of styling). **I am looking for a clean way to ensure that the PopUps are anchored to the control they are referring to so when the window is moved they are moved with them**...

One thought i had was to traverse the visual tree and manually set all PopUps IsOpen property to false...this seems like a bit of a "hack". It is less than ideal as it will presumably flicker among other things...Having said this a lot of the solutions i have seen so far on stackoverflow also seem to have their pitfalls. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Reference to the PlacementTarget.
DependencyObject myPopupPlacementTarget;

// Reference to the popup.
Popup myPopup; 

Window w = Window.GetWindow(myPopupPlacementTarget);
if (null != w)
 {
w.LocationChanged += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var offset = myPopup.HorizontalOffset;
    myPopup.HorizontalOffset = offset + 1;
    myPopup.HorizontalOffset = offset;
    };


}
```

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1600218/1064610)

Comment: The three lines for the offset can be written in a simpler way:
myPopup.HorizontalOffset++;
myPopup.HorizontalOffset--;