# Move WPF popup location when WinForms window's location changes

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, custom-controls

I have a custom control made in WPF, with a `ControlTemplate` containing a `Popup` control:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" 
       PopupAnimation="Fade"
       Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
       AllowsTransparency="True"
       IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsPopupOpen, Mode=OneWay}" 
       Placement="Bottom"  
       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_Border}">
```

the custom control is hosted in a WinForms app by the following code:

```
var wpfHost = new ElementHost();
wpfHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
wpfHost.Child = new TitleBar();
Controls.Add(wpfHost);
```

I want to make the popup reposition itself when the window location changes. I saw a couple of answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600218/how-can-i-move-a-wpf-popup-when-its-anchor-element-moves) suggesting to get the window reference and register to his `LocationChanged` event but it doesn't work for me since it is hosted in a winForms window.

Any suggestions would be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just connect to the `LocationChanged` event through the `ElementHost`?:

In `TitleBar` class:

```
public void WinFormsParent_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do what you want here
}
```

In hosting code:

```
var wpfHost = new ElementHost();
wpfHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
TitleBar titleBar = new TitleBar();
LocationChanged += titleBar.WinFormsParent_LocationChanged;
wpfHost.Child = titleBar;
Controls.Add(wpfHost);
```

Comment: The `Popup` is actually in a `ControlTemplate` of another custom control, defined in `TitleBar` but I still made it work. Thanks!