# How to always place PopUp under a ToggleButton in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, togglebutton

I want to place a popup under a togglebutton when I click on it. In this popup I want to add button and other controls. But how can I make sure that the popup window always will be under my togglebutton also when I resize my mian window.

My XAML code:

```
     <ToggleButton
    x:Name="userBtn"
    Margin="610,25,378,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"            
    Height="29"
    Grid.Column="2" 
    >
        <ToggleButton.Resources>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="imgNormal" UriSource="/Resources/home.jpg"/>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="imgHover" UriSource="/Resources/home_checked.jpg"/>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="imgChecked" UriSource="/Resources/home_checked.jpg"/>
        </ToggleButton.Resources>
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="32">
                                <Image x:Name="PART_Image" Height="22" Width="22" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="{StaticResource imgNormal}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PART_TEXT" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#FFAFADAD" FontSize="13" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.BtnDashboard}"  Margin="10,9,0,0"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource imgChecked}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_TEXT" Property="Foreground" Value="#79B539" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource imgHover}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_TEXT" Property="Foreground" Value="#79B539" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Opacity" Value="0.6"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>

    <Popup Name="UserMenuPopUp" PopupAnimation="Fade" Width="280" Height="auto" Margin="20" AllowsTransparency="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Placement="bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=userBtn}" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Userbtn}" StaysOpen="false" >
        <Border Margin="2,0,48,0" BorderThickness="1" Background="#EEEEEE" Height="105">
            <Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

C# code for click on togglebutton:

```
    private void UserBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get location, adn sender
        var element = (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton)sender;
        var location = element.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

        // Set popup location
        UserMenuPopUp.HorizontalOffset = (location.X);
        UserMenuPopUp.VerticalOffset = (location.Y);
        UserMenuPopUp.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Placement` and `PlacementTarget` properties of the `Popup` :)

```
<Popup Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=myToggleButton}" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Userbtn}" StaysOpen="False" />
```

The thing to note here is that, if  the window is moved when `Popup` is open, it wont move along.. What you could do is Bind the `IsOpen` property to `ToggleButton`'s `IsChecked` and set `StaysOpen`=False. Doing that, the Popup will close automatically, toggling the button back :) , also you wont be needing the C# code if you are to do this :)

OR here is a link to another SO post if it should stay open whatever the case be :
[Move a WPF Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600218/how-can-i-move-a-wpf-popup-when-its-anchor-element-moves)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @faztp12. The popup is in the right position, but when i move Main windows it does not follow :(

Comment: Perfect solution :) thank you very much. But without the C# code it will not work?

Comment: c# code is not needed anymore since the `Popup` is bound to the `ToggleButton`s IsChecked property :) Remove the UserBtn_Click event ;)

Comment: I removed UserBtn_Click event and it does not work? :(

Comment: did you add ' IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Userbtn}" ' in the `Popup` ?  :)

Comment: Yes :) - Just edit my question with the new xaml code.

Comment: also, if you explicitly asked the Popup to Open in c#, the binding would break :P mind that :P in that case this wont work :)

Comment: My bad xD - miss spell :) Thank you again for your help.