# Place a popup under a button (UWP, XAML, C#)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have created a `Button`. When the button is pressed a `Popup` appears. The Problem is, the popup is on the top left side while the button is on the Right side.

What do I have to do in XAML to make the popup appear under the button?

I even tried to place the popup in the top rightcorner via `HorizontalAllignment`. The Problem then is that the popup is outside my program (Right next to it. Literally).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to always place PopUp under a ToggleButton in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992577/how-to-always-place-popup-under-a-togglebutton-in-wpf)

Comment: Tried it.Placement and Placement target "is not recognized or accessible"

Answer (score 1):

just use the new **DropDownButton** in the new **winUi** library, it has a build in popup which comes under the button and the button even has an arrow on right side, it is perfect for your scenario. just use the nuget package, docs are here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/flyouts) which is attached to specific controls including `Button`, then You can use the [Placement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.FlyoutBase.Placement) property to specify where a flyout appears: Top, Left, Bottom, Right, or Full. So you can use the [Placement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.FlyoutBase.Placement) property to specify the flyout to appear under the button as the following code.

```
<Button Content="Click me">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
            <TextBlock Text="This is a flyout!"/>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

By the way, as we [suggestion in the Remark part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup#remarks),

> Do not use a [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup) if a [Flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout), [MenuFlyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout), [ToolTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltip) or [ContentDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/windows.ui.popups/contentdialog.md) ([MessageDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog) for a Windows 8 app) is more appropriate.