# How to make a Popup sticky to Window / move with Window in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, popup

In WPF I have Window with some buttons. Currently I have this functionality: I click a button and the Popup pops underneath the button.

**My goal is when dragging main Window the Popup to move with the Window so Popup remains under the button.**

Currently I'm using this code, but it seems it's not working - Popup pops, but when dragging main Window the Popup stays in the same place.

Here is my code:

```
    private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetPopUp();
    }

    private void ResetPopUp()
    {
        var offsetHor = popup.HorizontalOffset;
        var offsetVer = popup.VerticalOffset;

        popup.HorizontalOffset = offsetHor + 1;
        popup.HorizontalOffset = offsetHor - 1;

        popup.VerticalOffset = offsetVer + 1;
        popup.VerticalOffset = offsetVer - 1;
    }
```

I will be thankfully for any answers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I move a WPF Popup when its anchor element moves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600218/how-can-i-move-a-wpf-popup-when-its-anchor-element-moves)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what we use in our code. Maybe it can help.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.SizeChanged += delegate { this.ResetPopupLocation(); };

        this.LocationChanged += delegate { this.ResetPopupLocation(); };
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Popup> GetOpenPopups()
    {
        return PresentationSource.CurrentSources.OfType<HwndSource>()
            .Select(h => h.RootVisual)
            .OfType<FrameworkElement>()
            .Select(f => f.Parent)
            .OfType<Popup>()
            .Where(p => p.IsOpen);
    }

    private void ResetPopupLocation()
    {
        foreach (var popup in GetOpenPopups())
        {
            var offset = popup.HorizontalOffset;
            popup.HorizontalOffset = offset + 1;
            popup.HorizontalOffset = offset;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

you can combine PlacementTarget and Placement properties of popup to achieve it's positioning relative/centered to it's parent

something like below if you want the popup position at center of parent

```
        <Popup
            PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName = "parent_container_windowname"}"
            Placement="Center">
        </Popup>
```

if you want the placement of popup at top left corner of parent then you could use
Placement="Relative"