# Position WPF Window relative to the calling button

Tags: wpf, vb.net, window, position

I have a button which opens a new Window. How can I position the new Window relative to that button so that the Window right side is aligned with the button right side and Window top is aligned with the button bottom?

I tried to calculate the positions like this in the calling window, first of all to try make them aligned relative to the calling window itself but it seems not to be correct.

```
Dim SecondWin As New SecondWindow()
SecondWin.Top = Me.Top + Me.ActualHeight - SecondWin.Height
SecondWin.Left = Me.Left + Me.ActualWidth - SecondWin.Width
SecondWin.Show()
```

Comment: Try to set the position in [SourceInitialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sourceinitialized.aspx) Windows are really picky when setting positions or states on them. Also have you considered using a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx)?

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a job the [Popup control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is made for. [SO related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978186/binding-a-popup-to-another-controls-relative-screen-position)

Comment: I have considered a Popup but a regular Window in this case is better since it has all the functionality I need here. For example, it must be movable, resizable, closable and should have the title bar like in a regular Window. Don't know if Popup is capable of that. Why is setting the Window position difficult?